# Cannot convert String to byte array and vice versa in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, character-encoding

I am trying to convert a `byte array` to `String`. But the conversion alter the values. That means I cannot restore the `byte array` from the converted `String`.

```
byte[] array = {-64,-88,1,-2};
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
out.write(array);
String result = out.toString("UTF-8");
byte[] array2 = result.getBytes("UTF-8");
// output of array2: {-17,-65,-67,-17}
```

Comment: Actually, the result is longer than you wrote: `[-17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 1, -17, -65, -67]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a **charset** issue - utf-8 has more than 1 byte per char. Try the same with some 1-byte charset like

```
String result = out.toString("ISO-8859-15");
byte[] array2 = result.getBytes("ISO-8859-15");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a fixed single byte encoding, like the one Jan suggested. UTF-8 is a non-fixed encoding, that means, in certain cases you need more then one byte to encode a single code point. This is one of this cases since you use negative numbers. (See the table in the wiki page about [utf-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8))

What was interesting for me was the fact, that after converting the second array to a string, the strings were identical but the underlying arrays where not. 
But the point is, that the given character are not legit code points (or utf-8 representation of it) in which case the get replaced with the code point 65533, which in turn needs 3 bytes to be represented which explains the output:

```
[-17, -65, -67, -17, -65, -67, 1, -17, -65, -67]
```

The first two code points are represented as -17, -65, -67 and represent the illegal code point. The 1 represents a legit code point, so it "survived" the transformation and then last is again an illegal one.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can create a string out of an byte array by passing the array into the constructor like this

`String test = new String(byte_array);`

Also there's a method for String to convert a String to a byte-array that returns the array

I hope that helped at least a bit

Comment: From the javadoc: `Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the platform's default charset.`. Even if that works, it is a bad idea to rely on this as it may produce different results on other machines.